# How was the formula for calculating umask derived?

Tags: files, permissions, filesystems, umask

When using `umask`, I know that to get the resulting permission, the mask is first `NOT`ed and then it is `AND`ed with the default permission (`777` or `666`).

Now my question is, how was this formula derived? I mean, if **U** is the mask, **D** is the default permission, and **R** is the resulting permission, then where did

```
R = D AND NOT(U)
```

come from? It's not like someone has just thought of it out of nowhere.

Comment: Related - [Historically why is umask the way it is?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/230367/100397)